# How do you get the current value of a QtLabel in python? - PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I am wondering how to get the current value of a QtLabel in python. For example, if the label the text in the label is set to the word "Hello", how can I see if it is set to that or not?

Comment: The question answered is for C++ not python

Comment: I recommend you not only look only at the code since it is an important part but not the only one, the explanations were not placed by the users just for decorating the answer, for example one of them indicates: *Here is the documentation. [QLabel.text()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#text-prop)* which clearly indicates that you must use the `text()` method to obtain the information: `print(your_label.text())`